# iOS - Opening a PDF via Quicklook without using UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, quicklook

I am trying to open a PDF via the QuickLook framework without using UIScrollView...

I believe I'm missing something...

Where I believe I'm going wrong is that I need to use a QLPreviewController and on the QLPreviewController is a dataSource that has to conform to QLPreviewItem. The documentation states that NSURL does conform to QLPriewItem so I'm setting the preview.dataSource to an NSURL which is throwing an error:

**[NSURL numberOfPreviewItemsInPreviewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance**

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSURL numberOfPreviewItemsInPreviewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5b5f200'**

Which makes me think that NSURL does not conform.

all the code I think is necessary...

```
- (BOOL)previewController:(QLPreviewController *)controller shouldOpenURL:(NSURL *)url forPreviewItem:(id <QLPreviewItem>)item {

    return YES;
}

- (NSInteger) numberOfPreviewItemsInPreviewController: (QLPreviewController *) controller {

    return [documents count];
}

- (id <QLPreviewItem>) previewController: (QLPreviewController *) controller previewItemAtIndex: (NSInteger) index {

    return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[documents objectAtIndex:index] ofType:nil]];
}

- (void)pushPDF {

    QLPreviewController *preview = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];
    preview.dataSource = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MCIT_Quiz" ofType:@"pdf"]];
    //preview.currentPreviewItemIndex = 0;
    [self presentModalViewController:preview animated:YES];
    [preview release];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up just creating another class to hold my values and use as a datasource, a bit quick and dirty but it works.

```
//
//  documentList.h
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <QuickLook/QuickLook.h>


@interface DocumentList : NSObject <QLPreviewControllerDataSource, QLPreviewControllerDelegate> {
    NSArray *documents;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *documents;

-(void)createList;
-(NSInteger) numberOfPreviewItemsInPreviewController: (QLPreviewController *) controller;
- (id <QLPreviewItem>) previewController: (QLPreviewController *) controller previewItemAtIndex: (NSInteger) index;

@end
```

*inserting text to break up the files*

```
//
//  documentList.m
//

#import "DocumentList.h"

@implementation DocumentList

@synthesize documents;

-(void) createList {

    documents = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Quiz.pdf", nil] retain];
}

-(NSInteger) numberOfPreviewItemsInPreviewController: (QLPreviewController *) controller {

    return [documents count];
}

- (id <QLPreviewItem>) previewController: (QLPreviewController *) controller previewItemAtIndex: (NSInteger) index {

return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[documents objectAtIndex:index] ofType:nil]];
}

@end
```

Comment: If you really will only ever have the one, then why not get rid of documents, just return 1 and  put quiz.pdf into the previewItemAtIndex

Comment: Does that work? The documentation states it takes an int and not a file name there.

Comment: Ah, I get what you meant now.

Quiz.pdf is meant to be dynamic, above is just a simple example.

Comment: @Mytheral - I am looking at this answer from some time ago as I Have the same problem. I am just getting to grips with this and can you tell me how/where these methods are actually called?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't see where an NSURL conforms to QLPreviewControllerDataSource. I think you want

```
 preview.dataSource = self;
```

And then your already written routines (numberOfPreviewItemsInPreviewController and previewController) would return the appropriate NSURL (although it's not clear how "documents" gets filled.).

Comment: That works when the class itself conforms... but that's what I'm trying not to do.

Comment: Well, I would argue my point was still correct, that your code has to be the datasource that provides the preview items, whether you choose to factor it out into another class or not.

Comment: Can any on tell me how can i customize this(QLPreviewController)?

I want to give some option here for user as for text search,print and next & previous button.